# Reenable button default after event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button like this in my html:

```
<button id="target" url="foo.com">Button Text</button>
```

Then I have a method to disable it:

```
disableButton = function () {
    $("#target").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
};
```

And I have a second method that I call after the disableButton method to reenable it:

```
enableButton = function() {
    $('#target').unbind('click');
    $('#target').bind('click');
    $("#target").trigger('click');
};
```

The problem is, when I call enableButton(), it doesn’t trigger the button click. It only works if I call the enableButton() method and then manually click the button. Can anyone tell me how to make the enableButton() method trigger a button click when called?

Basically the workflow should be:

1) #target is clicked

2) #target is disabled until we get a response from some outside source

3) Response is received

4) Trigger a button click for #target without having to manually click the button again

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
disableButton = function () {
    $("#target").off("click");
};

enableButton = function() {
    $('#target').on("click", clickevent);
    $('#target').click();
};
```

where `clickevent` is a method which will be called when the button is clicked.

PS. Correct your code (quotes in the code). jQuery doesnt support unicode.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to manually have to click the button again to enable it. I've updated the question with the desired workflow.

Comment: Yes.. You need not have to click the button manually.. $("target").click(); will programmatically click it.. I guess this should work.

Answer (score 1):

> You do not need to `on/off` events, `click` events will not invoke if you `enable/disable` button.

Use `.prop('disabled', callback)` *set one or more properties for every matched element.*[[Ref](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)]

Try this:

```js
$('#enDis').on('click', function() {
  $('#myBtn').prop('disabled', function() {
    return !this.disabled;
  });
});

$('#myBtn').on('click', function() {
  alert('It is enabled!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='myBtn'>Main Button</button>
<button id='enDis'>Enable/Disable</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The problem here is that I want a method that, once invoked, triggers the button click event. With this, it appears that manually clicking the button is required.

Comment: All right! I hope you got the solution.. Good luck ;)